# How to get past "N" seconds data while processing current batch in Dstream

Tags: spark-streaming

I am new to the spark world. 
Having a weather  streaming applications receiving time based dstream (in form of tuples) of below type:

```
{
  timestamp, 
  { v1, v2, v3} 
}
```

where v1=temp, v2=humidity, v3=windrate

Example: `{ 01/05/2016 08:01:00,  { 25,4.2,10}}`

Now my requirement is to check temperature for every incoming record and if it crosses 35 then stop processing and dump last 10 mins data to hdfs for further investigation.

Comment: Any help/guidance will be gighly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to save all data received the last 10 minutes when you get a temp higher than 35 you have to follow these steps:

Create a dstream with a window value of 10 minutes and a slide duration of 1 seconds for instance: dstream.window(Minutes(10),Seconds(1)).

You will check the temperature received every seconds and if temp > 30, store the dstream on HDFS (containing all data received from batch_time - 10 minutes to batch_time).

Comment: Thanks Philippe Paulos for your kind help.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution.
Just started with sample code to see if it works.I am passing (k,v) from socket where v is temperature value and will check if it's greater than 30

Comment: val v1 = input.map { x => (x(0),x(1))}
val windowDStream  = v1.window(WINDOW_LENGTH, SLIDE_INTERVAL);
v1.foreachRDD(rdd =>
                 rdd.foreach(x => 
                    if(x._2.toInt > 30) {
                      println("key "+ x._1+ " with value "+ x._2)
                      windowDStream.saveAsTextFiles("D:\\output", "txt")
                    }))

Comment: But I am getting below exception with above code. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after starting a context is not supported
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.validateAtInit(DStream.scala:223)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.<init>(DStream.scala:65)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.<init>(ForEachDStream.scala:35)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.org$apache$spark$streaming$dstream$DStream$$foreachRDD(DStream.scala:653)
 at